# Creating a spotify style slider

Tags: javascript, user-interface

How would one go about implementing a slider like this on a website? Is there an out of the box solution using something like jQuery or even just css? What is this type of slider called?

[image: Spotify's group slider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of the component is called carousel. There are number of choices:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel